# Achievement link in ticker points to app's canvas page instead of achievement's url

Tags: facebook, url, ticker

I have an achievement registered for my application with 'url' parameter set to smth like

```
http://app-canvas-url.com/facebook_achievements/123.html
```

When achievement is published for a user ticker shows corresponding notification saying "{user name} achieved {achievement title} in {app name}". Click on this notification reveals a bigger popup that contain link to achievement that points to the url shown above.

That's ok. But ticker also has blocks saying "{user name} has earned 1 of 4 achievements in {app name}". Click on this block reveals popup with a list of all achievements available in the app. The problem is that links in this popup for some reason are pointing to urls like

```
http://apps.facebook.com/app-canvas-name/facebook_achievements/123.html
```

Looks like instead of pointing directly to achievement's url it prepends relative path to achievement with canvas page url of the app.

Does anyone experience similar problem? Is that an expected behavior? I didn't find anything about which urls are used in ticker so if you have seen any related info in docs, please, share the link.

Answer (score 1):

Before i had the same issue. today morning i solve this.
what i did is to change http to https for the achievements url sended to faceboook.
for example,
change
http://app-canvas-url.com/facebook_achievements/123.html
to
https://app-canvas-url.com/facebook_achievements/123.html

Answer (score 0):

You must have to create the separate pages for all the different types of achievements (ideal. You can also create only one page for all your achievements.).

Once you create those pages, you must have to enter the value for url in that page.

Type the correct url for that achievement.

Then go to the debugger tool

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Enter that url and check whether you are having any errors or not.
If any errors please solve that and if not then just go to the bottom of the page.

You'll find one link as "Graph API:". Click on that and will open the complete data for your achievement url.

Once done successfully, try to reload your application and check for all the urls for all the achievements.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you even read the question? I have no problems with registering achievements, but Facebook shows different link for the same achievements in different types of ticker notification.